# Prevent child block from cache (cacheable false) but not parent block (cacheable true) in magento 2.2.2

Tags: cache, magento2.2.2

I am working on a custom module template where I need to show some random string only in some part of a page and string should be generate randomly on every time page reload also the rest of the content should be cached content. For this, I have tried following code in layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="c.parent.block" template="Company_Module::parent.phtml" >
                <block class="Company\Module\Block\Myblock" name="m.child.block" template="Company_Module::child.phtml" />  
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**parent.phtml** file content :

```
..............
..............
/* Content should be cached */
..............
<?=$this->getChildhtml('m.child.block'); /* Prevent cache content*/ ?>
..............
..............
```

**child.phtml** file content :

```
<?php echo 'Random String : '. rand(); ?>
```

Above code working fine with my cache enabled store. But I want the above child block should not be cached for this I have passed `cacheable="false"` attribute with child block. Although this prevent the cache but its also prevent the cache for parent block. Is it possible to prevent the above child block from cache but not its parent block?

Note : I don't want to use any ajax request to generate random string.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with:

```
<?= $this->getChildhtml('m.child.block', false); ?>
```

With the second parameter is `false` (default `true`), Magento 2 will re-render block and don't get it from cache.

Comment: Thank you @Bill. But it makes both block same (cacheable false) as I mentioned in the question.